# Android: Change text color in ListView for singleChoice

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview set to use singleChoice. All I want to do is change the default background color to white and the text color to black. I cannot figure out how to do this. Here is my xml layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvSpeeds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/llToolbar"
    android:layout_below="@id/rgSpeedUnits"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:divider="#ff000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scrollingCache="true" />
```

EDIT: I should have pointed out that I want to change this only using xml layout files and NOT in code. I already know how to do this in code. Using a custom layout other than android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice forces you to implement an adapter, bind, write more code, and so on. From viewing a lot more posts, it does not appear possible to change the text color using only xml. In fact, it doesn't seem possible to change anything on a row as the underlying layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice is not accessible.

Comment: Create different layout for textView,set text colcor which you want and used this layout to in your Adapter which you have used. have a look to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835468/make-a-textview-inside-a-listview-use-the-default-listview-row-style) it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

for a list view Use android selector
like this

and save it with `anyname.xm`l and giveits reference to background of your list

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/about_btn_hover"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/about_btn"></item> 

</selector>
```

and for changing text color add color folder in your res directory 
create an xml save it `textchangecolor.xml` 
and add the following lines to it

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:color="@color/whiteColor"></item>
    <item android:color="@color/bluetxt"></item> 
</selector>
```

and give its refernce to the textcolor

Comment: Perhaps you would like to include what about_btn is along with all the other constants you left out. As it is, your code is useless.

Comment: i have just added xmls not Code and Selector will pick automatically its state  with its behavior of default and state_pressed.

Comment: Your code is useless. Nobody can copy and paste it and expect it to work. Please delete your solution. You're wasting my time.

Comment: the only problem I have with this solution is ListView doesn't have a textColor property.

Comment: Thanks Usman, I think I got this, I changed the Style of the corresponding View from `android:listViewStyle` to `@style/ListViewChangeSelectedTextColor` and added the following code to my `styles.xml` file: `<style name ="ListViewChangeSelectedTextColor" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/select_text_white_else_black</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 1):

try to this:

insert to this code in adapter in getview mathod:

```
LinearLayout mRowLayout = (LinearLayout) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_item_layout);
            final TextView title = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_item);

            title.setText(Massage[position]);

            mRowLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {


                                    title.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                            });
```

here list_item code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/list_item_layout"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_single"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">


<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
        android:id="@+id/list_item"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This requires creating code for an adapter, adding RadioButtons and adding more code to handle the radio buttons. Looking for a pure xml solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find was to use styles.xml and set a theme for my dialogs.

styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/text</item>
    + other styles
</style>
```

In Java Built Dialogs:

```
ContextThemeWrapper theme;
theme = ContextThemeWrapper(view.getContext(), R.style.DialogTheme);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(theme);
```

In XML built Dialogs:

```
<myLayout
    ....
    android:theme="@style/DialogTheme" />
```